# How to stop Windows explorer asking "are you sure?"?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

Whenever I move or delete files in Windows XP, the explorer seems to have to ask me, if I really want to do it, whenever there's a read-only file, or an executable, or for some other strange reasons. This is very annoying, especially in case of executables, since they're surely no more valuable than regular files. Moreover, it [slows down](https://superuser.com/questions/242091/windows-xp-slow-directory-move) operations which should take no time.

I mostly use better tools like FreeCommander, but sometimes the explorer is handy. 
Is there a way to switch this "feature" off?

**Update:** *This is NOT about the confirmation, when I press DELETE.* This confirmation is OK and I want to keep it. What I want to get rid of, is the additional confirmation for deleting or moving files Windows considers important (but I do not). For example, when moving a large directory, Windows seems to look at all the files therein, in order to ask me if I really want to move foo.exe. I say "Yes to ALL", then it finds a read-only file, I say "Yes to ALL", then it finds... and finally I find myself swearing like a sailor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: A picture says more than a thousand words]

---

Files are read-only for that purpose, consider command line movement or other more specialized tool if you want to force movement. [**TeraCopy**](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) allows you to force movement using a shell extension...

[image]

Comment: Hahah wow I feel like an idiot now. +1

Comment: @Ciaran: Well, I looked in the group policy editor first... ._.

Comment: This is not what I asked. This is about the confirmation, when I press DELETE. This confirmation is OK and I want to keep it. What I want to get rid of, is the *additional* confirmation for *deleting or moving* files Windows considers important (but I do not).

Comment: @maaartinus: You did, I don't see "additional confirmation for deleting or moving files" in your question.

Comment: Have you got a screenshot for that? I'm always either able to press OK and it's gone or get an access error. I don't know any other message other then when moving a file, I'm asked if I want to copy/replace the file

Comment: @TomWij: Indeed, I didn't say "additional", but I said "whenever there's a read-only file, or an executable" and that's the important part. I see my question needs clarification.

Comment: @maaartinus: Updated twice, see bottom of my answer. It's customizable...

Comment: I didn't thought that this could be done so easily as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found is to right click the Recycle Bin and go to properties.  Disable the delete confirmation by unchecking the box.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very messy [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that will do what you want.

I say messy because...

1. You press your delete key. It then tries to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> as if you did it in Explorer. This also copies a string with the path to the file to the clipboard
2. It won't distinguish between windows. Your delete key is gone if you use this.
3. It has to wait a bit before it can paste the path into the command prompt
4. This is a stupid way of pressing enter after you press delete. Seriously, it doesn't slow anything down.

   send, {control down}c{control up}
   Run cmd
   Sleep,300
   send, del /q %clipboard% {return} exit {return}

Now, you can pretty it up somewhat by wrapping the whole thing in a check to see if it's an Explorer folder. This will remove the dilemma of it trying to do something like `del /q http://superuser.com/questions/pressing-del-then-enter-is-too-slow-for-me` if you haven't got a file path copied.

If you need more info on AutoHotKey, Google is your friend.

Comment: Interesting idea, but too risky in case I do something else in the meantime, and get something like "C:\" in the keyboard. Moreover and more importantly, it solves a problem I do not have (see my comment to TomWij).

Comment: Hmm, just tried it on a read-only file and didn't get any prompt. Any chance of a screenshot? I'm using Windows 7 so it might be that.

Comment: Here are three screenshots in one image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4971686/YesToAll.png

Comment: @maaartinus: See bottom of my answer, it's customizable...