# Instantly move huge folder to another directory on same drive in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-transfer

I have 1 TB of files in `D:/Foo` but I want to move it to `D:/`. It takes several hours to move this by simply dragging the contents of `Foo` to its parent directory. Since this is on the same drive, is there a way to change the directory of these files without dragging/dropping and waiting for them to move?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/242091/windows-xp-slow-directory-move?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the command prompt (cmd.exe) and navigate to `Foo` then use the command `move FileToBeMoved ..` and it moved instantly.